# Correct use of PEP 508 environment markers in setup.cfg

Tags: python, python-3.x, setuptools, python-packaging

I am trying to make use of [PEP 496 -- Environment Markers](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0496/) and [PEP 508 -- Dependency specification for Python Software Packages](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0508/) by specifying dependencies that only make sense on specific OS.

My `setup.py` looks like this:

```
import setuptools
assert setuptools.__version__ >= '36.0'

setuptools.setup()
```

My minimal `setup.cfg` looks like this:

```
[metadata]
name = foobar
version = 1.6.5+0.1.0

[options]
packages = find:

install_requires =
    ham >= 0.1.0
    eggs >= 8.1.2
    spam >= 1.2.3; platform_system=="Darwin"
    i-love-spam >= 1.2.0; platform_system="Darwin"
```

However, when trying to install such a package with `pip install -e foobar/`, it fails with:

```
pip._vendor.pkg_resources.RequirementParseError: Invalid requirement, parse error at "'; platfo'"
```

I guess it does not expect semicolon there. But how am I supposed to use environment markers then?

Comment: I'm rather surprised you got that far... I always thought `install_requires` was an argument to `setup()`, not a command-line flag.

Comment: @Kevin It's not command-line flag either — it's inside of `setup.cfg`, which is another source of confusion (https://stackoverflow.com/q/44878600/472695). To be honest, I almost hate Python's packaging system.

Comment: I've packaged and distributed a Python library with Setuptools and had no need of setup.cfg.  I think the short answer here is "move everything into setup.py and delete setup.cfg."

Comment: @Kevin, next step would be to throw out setuptools and use distutils, because setuptools is too mainstream. On the serious note, why one would go back 9 years in time to end up where python packaging started - at the archaic "setup.py"?

Comment: http://packaging.python.org has two brief mentions of setup.cfg, and the rest is about setup.py.  I don't know who told you that setup.cfg was the new hotness, but they're mistaken.

Comment: I think Conda uses a colon rather than a semicolon. I have never used setup.cfg, but worth a try?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One character. That's all you were missing. You had `platform_system="Darwin"` instead of `platform_system=="Darwin"` (the very last line of your `install_requires`). It works fine this way:

```
[metadata]
name = foobar
version = 1.6.5+0.1.0

[options]
packages = find:

install_requires =
    ham >= 0.1.0
    eggs >= 8.1.2
    spam >= 1.2.3; platform_system=="Darwin"
    i-love-spam >= 1.2.0; platform_system=="Darwin"
```

It's not necessary but your `setup.py` could be simplified too.

```
import setuptools

setup(setup_requires=['setuptools>=36.0'])
```

Unlike those commenting before, I like using `setup.cfg`. It's clean and easy. If you want to use the information from `setup.cfg` at runtime, it's easy to parse:

```
from setuptools.config.setupcfg import read_configuration

conf_dict = read_configuration('/home/user/dev/package/setup.cfg')
```

[More setup.cfg info](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/declarative_config.html)

Comment: Damn... for all those years.

Comment: I was looking for `setup.cfg` info because, admittedly, the documentation isn't great and then stumbled on this from the Google. BLTN?