# Is `setup.cfg` deprecated?

Tags: python, python-3.x, setuptools, distutils, python-packaging

It's not completely clear to me, what is the status of `setup.cfg`. I am looking for solutions for my [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44878440/472695) about PEP 508 environment markers, and I became totally confused.

To me it seems that `setup.cfg` is an improvement over `setup.py`, because it's declarative, does not involve running arbitrary code to make package installable, makes it harder to distribute malicious Python packages, makes it easier to run Python package registries etc.

So, [here in `setuptools` docs](http://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#configuring-setup-using-setup-cfg-files) it's mentioned that setuptools got support for setup.cfg in `30.3.0 (8 Dec 2016)` version, which is quite recent. So, this has to be a new thing, right?

Not quite. [`distutils` had support for `setup.cfg` for a long time](https://docs.python.org/2.6/distutils/configfile.html), at least since 2.6. It's been 9 years already.

At the same time, [here in `wheel` docs](https://wheel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#defining-conditional-dependencies) it's been said that `setup.cfg` is now deprecated, and it's preferred to provide environment markers via `extras_require` parameter. And it mentions setuptools, so it isn't about possibly-deprecated distutils flavor of `setup.cfg`.

So, what is actually going on? Is `setup.cfg` deprecated, or the most recent way to do things?

Comment: The plan is to deprecate `setup.cfg` eventually - follow [_#3214 Eventually deprecate setup.cfg with automatic conversion to pyproject.toml_](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/3214) for progress.

Answer (score 23):

I'd like to add a few notes on recent developments:

[PEP 518](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0518/#sticking-with-setup-cfg), first drafted in 2016, was marked as final in April of 2020. I'm interpreting it as an invitation to use `pyproject.toml` instead of `setup.cfg`. Quoting from the PEP:

> There are two issues with `setup.cfg` used by setuptools as a general
> format. One is that they are `.ini` files which have issues as mentioned
> in the [configparser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html#module-configparser) discussion above. The other is that the schema for
> that file has never been rigorously defined and thus it's unknown
> which format would be safe to use going forward without potentially
> confusing setuptools installations.

From [black's documentation](https://black.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage_and_configuration/the_basics.html#what-on-earth-is-a-pyproject-toml-file):

> [PEP 518](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0518/) defines `pyproject.toml` as a configuration file to store build
> system requirements for Python projects. With the help of tools like
> [Poetry](https://poetry.eustace.io/) or [Flit](https://flit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) it can fully replace the need for `setup.py` and
> `setup.cfg` files.

[pip 19.0](https://github.com/pypa/pip/blob/main/NEWS.rst#190-2019-01-22) (2019-01-22) implemented [PEP 517](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0517/) to allow projects to specify a build backend via `pyproject.toml`.

[PEP 621](https://peps.python.org/pep-0621/) which specifies a a standard way of storing project metadata in pyproject.toml, was marked as final on March 3, 2021.

`setuptools` has an open issue titled "[Eventually deprecate `setup.cfg` with automatic conversion to `pyproject.toml`](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/3214)".

**Disclaimer:** I feel <del>totally</del> lost in Python's packaging jungle myself.

**Recommended further reading:** [Why you shouldn't invoke setup.py directly](https://blog.ganssle.io/articles/2021/10/setup-py-deprecated.html) by Paul Ganssle.

Comment: Or Python could have just adopted `package.json`, especially given it fits nice into Python's internal import machinery... But, [xkcd 927](https://xkcd.com/927/) is on point again.

Comment: re lost in the jungle: "Whenever something can be done in two ways, someone will be confused.
Whenever something is a matter of taste, discussions can drag on forever.
    -- B. Stroustrup"

Comment: Also see [PEP 621 - Storing project metadata in pyproject.toml](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0621/)

Comment: PEP 517/518 are no longer provisional.

Answer (score 4):

Nope, `setup.cfg` it is not deprecated and the documentation you mention is misleading.

There were serious reasons like security related to the fact that `setup.py` needed execution and that's the main reason of moving away from it.

Here is the dirty trick for extras:

```
[options.extras_require]
pdf = ReportLab>=1.2; RXP
rest = docutils>=0.3; pack ==1.1, ==1.3
```

Comment: Why is it dirty? That example comes straight out from documentation