# Should I be using only pyproject.toml?

Tags: python, setuptools, pypi, python-packaging

Should I be using only pyproject.toml or use it with setup.py and setup.cfg? Or perhaps some other combination of them.

I can't find any definitive answer to this question so I'd be pleased if someone could enlighten the matter.

Comment: I think the only answer is "not yet". `pyproject.toml` is *intended* to be a tool-agnostic file, but not all tools support it, and I don't think most code bases *need* to be tool-agnostic. (If you or your organization always uses `pip`, then there's no need to support `poetry`, for example.)

Comment: Depends on your needs. If you support only modern systems (no EOL versions) and only PEP660 enabled backends (no setuptools [yet](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/pull/3488), so I doubt it is your case) - you may go with pyproject.toml only, but users won't like this. But you can keep all configuration in `pyproject.toml` and use one-liner as setup.py (no setup.cfg; in setup.py just `import setuptools; setuptools.setup()`).

Comment: Yes. As of today, I would definitely recommend the default to be `pyproject.toml`. If your project stumbles unto something that prevents from using `pyproject.toml`, then fall back to something else, but there are less and less hold-offs by the day. Even _setuptools_ can be used with `pyproject.toml` only (without `setup.cfg` and `setup.py`).

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44878600, https://stackoverflow.com/q/62983756

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the downsides to relying purely on pyproject.toml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75588250/what-are-the-downsides-to-relying-purely-on-pyproject-toml)

Comment: That this perfectly reasonable question does not have a reasonable answer but is closed as being "opinion-based" says a lot about the awful mess of the Python packaging world.

Answer (score -1):

I recently published a Python library to PyPI and I only used the **pyproject.toml** file to build and distribute the package (I did **not** have a need for *setup.py* or *setup.cfg*).

If that is your use-case (publishing the package) then **pyproject.toml** is sufficient. I hope this information helps.

---

In case you are interested, the package's GitHub is linked here: https://github.com/Shayan-H20/IG-Trading-Historical-Data

Answer (score -1):

pyproject.toml is sufficient for most projects. It's introduced in PEP 518. However, a complicated project would probably require a setup.py or a MANIFEST.in if needed. Check the Python packaging guide: https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/overview/

You can check out more info about setuptools and setup.py in here: https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/discussions/setup-py-deprecated/#setup-py-deprecated

This question also provides additional information: [What is pyproject.toml file for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62983756/what-is-pyproject-toml-file-for)

Generally, pyproject.toml is needed if you want to publish a project. It includes basic settings, configurations, dependencies, links, and info about your project. setup.py is not mandatory, but can be used to configure your project. A fact worth noting is that although setuptools and setup.py is not deprecated, commands like `python setup.py install` have been replaced by `python -m pip install`.