# What are the downsides to relying purely on pyproject.toml?

Tags: python, setuptools, setup.py, python-packaging, pyproject.toml

Say you have a Python program that you can successfully package using only `pyproject.toml`. What are the downsides? Why use `setup.py` or `setup.cfg` in this case?

Comment: The downside from setup.py is that it has no scripting capabilities like using a fully functional python file has.  However this is also a feature in the sense that it is more secure, stable, and simpler and easier to maintain in many cases

Comment: I have been using pip for a decade, now poetry and pyproject.toml now for more than two years. I have not come across any downside. Poetry and pyproject.toml are newer technologies and fix many of issues with old setup.py based workflow.

Comment: This question is being shutdown for being opinion based, and I disagree. There are real, objective, and fact-based reasons for choosing to use a `setup.py` or not. I would advise against closing this question for enticing opinion based answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no downside in not having a `setup.py`. It is just that in some particular cases some elements of the packaging can not be expressed in a descriptive manner (which means without code) in `setup.cfg` or `pyproject.toml`. This can range from some custom dynamic package metadata to the handling of packaging for custom non-Python code and many other things.

My recommendation is:

- Avoid using `setup.py` as much as possible, if you can do without this script completely, then do without it
- Place the standard parts in [`pyproject.toml`](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/pyproject_config.html):

  - `[build-system]` section, it is strongly recommended to have this section independently of whether or not you have a `setup.cfg` file and/or `setup.py` script
  - [`[project]`](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/specifications/declaring-project-metadata/) section, and avoid dynamic fields as much as possible
- For the parts that are specific to *setuptools*, you can choose to have them in `pyproject.toml` (under the [`[tool.setuptools]` section](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/pyproject_config.html#setuptools-specific-configuration)) or in `setup.cfg`, as you prefer

***Related***:

- [Is `setup.py` deprecated?](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/discussions/setup-py-deprecated/)
- [How to modernize a `setup.py` based project?](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/modernize-setup-py-project/#modernize-setup-py-project)

Comment: The description in this answer about the `[build-system]` section being compulsory is false. It's detailed in the [PEP](https://peps.python.org/pep-0518/#build-system-table) that _tools should not require the existence of the `[build-system]` table_, and that setuptools + wheel will be assumed as the build system requirements if the build system section is absent.

Comment: @wim, I have rephrased this.