# Exclude external library with setuptools

Tags: setuptools, python-packaging

I'm trying to exclude a specific library from being installed whenever users install my package via pip while not on macOS

Here's my logic:

```
if platform.system() == "Darwin":
    install_packages = setuptools.find_packages()
else:
    install_packages = setuptools.find_packages(exclude=["appscript==1.2.0"])
```

Then in **setuptools.setup** I use: `packages=install_packages`

This doesn't seem to work..

```
Building wheels for collected packages: appscript
  Building wheel for appscript (setup.py) ... error
```

How do I exclude this package from my setup? I'm new to this, so I'm sure I missed something.

Thanks!

Comment: Use environment markers: [_PEP 508_](https://peps.python.org/pep-0508/#environment-markers). Something like `appscript==1.2.0 ; platform_system=="Darwin"` in your `install_requires`. Consider also moving to `pyproject.toml`, to avoid writing such dynamic code-based logic in `setup.py` which is very much discouraged nowadays; in favor of static descriptive configuration files (`pyproject.toml` or `setup.cfg`).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49501010/11138259

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If anyone else stumbles upon this looking for an easy fix, here's what I did

```
from pip._internal import main as pip

if platform.system() == "Darwin":
    pip(['install', '--user', 'appscript==1.2.0'])
```

Windows still throws an error when doing a pip install, but if I run it a second time it installed it just fine without any issues.

Comment: This is very bad practice. This will break sooner or later. And it is entirely unnecessary. -- Use PEP 508 environment markers, this is the way to go and will work reliably and will be compatible with the whole Python packaging ecosystem.